# Import .IBD files into MySQL server

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find a way to import "old copied" .ibd files into a new installed MYSQL Server 8.0

Comment: See [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.11/en/partial.restoring.single.html) but NOTE:If you have a clean backup of an .ibd file, you can restore it to the MySQL installation **from which it originated**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need to know the *exact* structure of the table (the `CREATE TABLE` statement).

1. Create the table with the same structure.
2. Run `ALTER TABLE table_name DISCARD TABLESPACE;`
3. Copy the ibd file to table_name.ibd in the target location
4. Run `ALTER TABLE table_name IMPORT TABLESPACE;`

This may not work if you didn't `FLUSH TABLES table_name FOR EXPORT;` before you backed it up.

Comment: Awesome, please mark the answer as correct, then. :-)

Comment: I had problem with "Error Code: 1812. Tablespace is missing for table....", on import command. So I needed add permissions for coppied ibd file. That solved my problem. May be usefull for someone.