# Can not import ibd to mysql in xampp

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I got a wordpress website, today it give me an error on xampp, I managed to re-install xampp, before this, I create a backup from `mysql/data` db folders, it contains `ibd` and `frm` files, I installed fresh xampp and I paste those db folders to `mysql/data` but when I open phpmyadmin it won't let open any tables and give me an error:

> #1932 - Table ... doesn't exist in engine

I googled about 3hrs and figured out I can restore lost data from ibd file, so I follow instruction from this **[article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61727167/import-ibd-files-into-mysql-server)** but after run `ALTER TABLE table_name IMPORT TABLESPACE;` it give me another error:

> internal error: Drop all secondary indexes before importing table

I am not mysql expert, I don't know how to restore my data, at least from `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` with these `ibd` files, I got very important data on this table, my bad is never run a sql backup before this happen! now I wondering if there is a way to restore data from those files or I failed? is there any hope?

I would be thankful for any help!